# LibGDX random error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I just installed LibGDX on IntelliJ IDEA, and once I run the application, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
at com.trewi_.game.Game.create(Game.java:16)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: badlogic.jpg (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:137)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:223)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 7 more

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is the file "badlogic.jpg" ?

Comment: It's in the assets folder by default. I have set the working directory to my assets folder, and that fixed it, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you didn't set up the asset folder properly.

Read [this article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea) for a step by step guide.

I use Android Studio for libgdx because it is targeted for android and is based off of Intelij Idea.

I'll show you how to do it on Android Studio which is pretty similar to Intelij idea.

First click on the Select run/debug configuration:

[image]

Then Click on Edit Configurations:

[image]

And then click on the Desktop Section and make sure that the working directory is your assets directory:

[image]